# what's undefined here Event Object or the inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

i have this sample code i was writing for OTP verification in Reactjs when i run this code the output shows an error that:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import '../src/component.css'

export default function Component(){

  

  const[count,setCount] = useState(0);

  const inpRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(()=>{

    

    setTimeout(()=>{

      setCount(count+1)

    },1000);

  

    const handleInput =(e,index)=>{

      const current = inpRef.current[index];

      let next = inpRef.current[index+1];

      let prev = inpRef.current[index-1];

      

     const expression = /^\d+$/

     const isValid = expression.test(e.target.value);

     

     if(!isValid){

       e.target.value = "";

       return;

     }

      if (e.target.value.length >1){

        e.target.value ="";

      }

     

    }

    

    inpRef.current.forEach((input,index)=>{

      input.addEventListener('input',handleInput.bind(null,index))

    })

   return ()=>{

     inpRef.current.forEach((input,index)=>{

      input.removeEventListener('input',handleInput.bind(null,index))

    })

   }

  },[])

  

  return(

    <>

    <p> Counter : {count}</p>

    <h4>Now enter the OTP</h4>

   

    <div className="whole">

    <h5>Send the OTP to your phone Number</h5>

     <div className="container">

    {[...Array(6)].map((_,index)=>{

      return <input className="text-field" type ="number"

      ref = {(ref) =>{

        inpRef.current[index] = ref;

      }} 

      key ={index}

      />

    })}

    </div>

    <button className ="btn">SUBMIT</button>

    </div>

    

    </>

    )


}
```

what am i doing wrong here? iwant an OTP verification page with 6input boxes so that whenever i put or add a value to an input field the focus keeps shifting to the next input element and when i press backspace the focus should shift back towards the previous element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have arguments of `handleInput` in wrong order, here `index` is `event` and `e` is `index`. Hence `e.target.value` is `undefined`.

change

```
const handleInput = (e, index) => { ... }
```

to

```
const handleInput = (index, e) => { ... }
```

see [codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-grass-mkbqv2?file=/src/Test.tsx).